# Funcion eliminar en un arbol AVL

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos

Buenas tardes estoy implementando la funcion eliminar en un arbol AVL en java pero no cumple con lo que tiene que hacer.

Por lo que veo el problema no es en las funciones de eliminar un dato porqu son las mismas que uso en un ABB normal en el cual no me dan problema, el asunto en el AVL es en la parte de la rotacion y actualizacion, es aca dondde esta el problema dado que me da null el valor que regresa de la funcion de rotacion.

Si alguien lo pudo realizar de distinta forma le agradeceria el codigo con una explicacion, gracias

```
    public void eliminar(int dato)
    {
        if(raiz != null)
        {
            raiz = eliminarAVL(raiz, dato);
        }
        tamaño--;
    }
    
    
    private Nodo eliminarAVL(Nodo actual, int dato)
    {
        if(actual == null)
        {
            return actual;
        }
        
        if(actual.edad > dato)
                
        {
            actual.izquierda = eliminarAVL(actual.izquierda, dato);
        }
        else if(actual.edad < dato)
        {
            actual.derecha = eliminarAVL(actual.derecha, dato);
        }
        else
        {
            if(actual.edad == dato)
        {
            if(buscarHoja(actual) == true)
            {
                eliminarHoja(actual);
            }
            else if(buscar1Hijo(actual) == true)
            {
                eliminar1Hijo(actual);
            }
            else{
                
                Nodo mayor = getMayor(actual.izquierda);
        Nodo aux1 = mayor;
        
        eliminar(mayor.edad);
      actual.edad = aux1.edad;  //asigno a auxiliar el valor del mayor 
        
            }
        }
        }
        
        //actualiza la altura
      
            actual.FE = Math.max(obtenerFactorDeEquilibrio(actual.derecha), obtenerFactorDeEquilibrio(actual.izquierda)) + 1;
        
            
                //equilibrar el arbol
                
       int fe = obtenerFactorDeEquilibrio(actual);
       
       if(fe > 1 || obtenerFactorDeEquilibrio(actual.izquierda) >= 0)
       {
           return rotacionSimpleDerecha(actual);
       }
       
       if(fe < -1 || obtenerFactorDeEquilibrio(actual.derecha) <= 0)
       {
           return  rotacionSimpleIzquierda(actual);
       }
       
       
       if(fe > 1 || obtenerFactorDeEquilibrio(actual.izquierda) < 0)
       {
           actual.izquierda = rotacionSimpleIzquierda(actual.izquierda);
           return  rotacionSimpleDerecha(actual);
       }
       
       if (fe < -1 || obtenerFactorDeEquilibrio(actual.derecha) > 0)
       {
           actual.derecha = rotacionSimpleDerecha(actual.derecha);
           return rotacionSimpleIzquierda(actual);
       }
            
       return actual;
}
```

Ahora tengo funciones para saber si es hoja o hijo

```
    public boolean buscarHoja(Nodo aux)
    {
        if(aux.izquierda == null && aux.derecha == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    Funcion buscar Hijo

    public boolean buscar1Hijo(Nodo aux)
    {
        if((aux.derecha != null && aux.izquierda == null) || (aux.derecha == null && aux.izquierda != null))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Ahora las funciones para eliminar

```
      public void eliminarHoja(Nodo aux)
    {
         Nodo anterior = buscarPadre(aux.edad);
       
            if(aux == raiz)
            {
                raiz = null;
            }
            else
            {
                if(aux == anterior.izquierda)
                {
                   anterior.izquierda = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    anterior.derecha = null;
                }
            }
    }
```

Funcion eliminar hijo

```
    public void eliminar1Hijo(Nodo aux)
    {
          Nodo padre = buscarPadre(aux.edad);
        
        if(aux == raiz)
        {
            if(aux.izquierda != null)
            {
                raiz = aux.izquierda;
            }else{
                raiz = aux.derecha;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(aux.izquierda != null){  //aux tiene hijo izquierdo
                if(aux == padre.izquierda)
                {
                    padre.izquierda = aux.izquierda;
                }else{
                    padre.derecha = aux.izquierda;
                }
            }
            else{
                if(aux.derecha != null){
                    if(aux == padre.derecha)
                    {
                        padre.derecha = aux.derecha;
                    }else{
                        padre.izquierda = aux.derecha;
                    }
                }
            }
        }     
    }
```

Uso una funcion para obtener el mayor del subarbol izquierdo para remplazar en el caso de eliminar 2 hijos

```
      public Nodo getMayor(Nodo mayor)
    {
        while(mayor.derecha != null)
        {
            mayor = mayor.derecha;
        }
        return mayor;
    }
```

Aca les dejo las funciones que se encargar de rotar los nodos

```
      //rotacion simple a la izquierda
    public Nodo rotacionSimpleIzquierda(Nodo actual)
    {
        Nodo k1 = actual.izquierda;
        actual.izquierda = k1.derecha;
        k1.derecha = actual;
       
        actual.FE = Math.max(obtenerFactorDeEquilibrio(actual.izquierda), obtenerFactorDeEquilibrio(actual.derecha)) + 1;
        k1.FE = Math.max(obtenerFactorDeEquilibrio(k1.izquierda), obtenerFactorDeEquilibrio(k1.derecha)) + 1;
         return k1; // para que tome el lugar de actual en el arbol
    }
    
    public Nodo rotacionSimpleDerecha(Nodo actual)
    {
        Nodo k2 = actual.derecha;
        actual.derecha = k2.izquierda;
        k2.izquierda = actual;
        
        actual.FE = Math.max(obtenerFactorDeEquilibrio(actual.izquierda), obtenerFactorDeEquilibrio(actual.derecha)) + 1;
        k2.FE = Math.max(obtenerFactorDeEquilibrio(k2.izquierda), obtenerFactorDeEquilibrio(k2.derecha)) + 1;
        
        return k2;
    }
        
    public Nodo rotacionDobleDerecha(Nodo actual)
    {
        Nodo k2;
       actual.derecha = rotacionSimpleIzquierda(actual.derecha);
       k2 = rotacionSimpleDerecha(actual);
        
       
        return k2;
    }
    
    
    public Nodo rotacionDobleIzquierda(Nodo actual)
    {
        Nodo k1;
       actual.izquierda = rotacionSimpleDerecha(actual.izquierda);
      k1 = rotacionSimpleIzquierda(actual);
      
        return k1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> *Aca dejo la solucion a mi problema. Tenia que ver con las rotaciones de los nodos.*

```
public void EliminarAVL(int dato)
  
{
     
 Nodo aux =buscarNodo(dato);
  
      if(aux.edad == dato)
      {
          eliminarNodo(aux);
      }
  
  
 //actualiza altura
 aux.altura = Math.max(altura(aux.izquierda), altura(aux.derecha)) + 1;
 
 // calcular el (FE)
 int fe = getFactorDeEquilibrio(aux);
 
 /*
 RSD
                 20 (2)  fe > 1
                /
               12 (1)    actual.izquierda fe >= 0
              /
            5 (0)
 */
  if(fe > 1 && getFactorDeEquilibrio(aux.izquierda) >= 0)
  {
       rotacionSimpleDerecha(aux);
  }
  
  /*
  RSI
           5(-2)  fe < -1
                  \
                      12(-1) actual.derecha fe <= 0
                                 \
                                   20(0)
  */
  if(fe < -1 && getFactorDeEquilibrio(aux.derecha) <= 0)
  {
       rotacionSimpleDerecha(aux);
  }
  
  /*
  RDD
            12(2) fe > 1
           /
         5(-1)    actual.izquierda fe < 1
              \
                8(0)
  */
  if(fe > 1 && getFactorDeEquilibrio(aux.izquierda) < 0)
  {
      aux.izquierda = rotacionSimpleIzquierda(aux.izquierda);
       rotacionSimpleDerecha(aux);
  }
  
  /*
  RDI
        5(-2)  fe < -1
            \
             12(1) actual.derecha fe > 0
           /
        8(0)
  */
  if(fe < -1 && getFactorDeEquilibrio(aux.derecha) > 0)
  {
      aux.derecha = rotacionSimpleDerecha(aux.derecha);
       rotacionSimpleIzquierda(aux);
  }
  
 tamaño--;
```

}

```
public void eliminarNodo(Nodo actual)
    {
            if(buscarHoja(actual) == true)
            {
                eliminarHoja(actual);
            }
            else if(buscar1Hijo(actual) == true)
            {
                eliminar1Hijo(actual);
            }
            else
            {
            
            Nodo mayor = getMayor(actual.izquierda);
    Nodo aux1 = mayor;
    
        eliminarNodo(mayor);
  actual.edad = aux1.edad;  //asigno a auxiliar el valor del mayor 
    
        }
    
}
```